# $\frac{\binom{p^2}{np}}{p} \mod p$ for $p$ prime

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime. The expression $\frac{\binom{p^2}{i}}{p}\in \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by $p$ unless $i$ is a multiple of $p$ -- this is easy to see by expanding and comparing the number of multiples of $p$ in the numerator and the denominator. I am interested if there is another formula for this expression, maybe even something that allows to do computations 'by hand'. Here are some examples for small primes, using computer algebra.

I will write the string $$\left(\frac{\binom{p^2}{p}}{p},\frac{\binom{p^2}{2p}}{p},..., \frac{\binom{p^2}{p^2-p}}{p}\right) \mod p$$ for each $p$.

$(1)$ for $p=2$;

$(1,1)$ for $p=3$;

$(1,2,2,1)$ for $p=5$;

$(1,3,5,5,3,1)$ for $p=7$;

$(1,5,4,8,9,8,4,5,1)$ for $p=11$;

$(1,6,9,3,8,2,2,8,3,9,6,1)$ for $p=13$.

Is there any pattern here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Wilson’s theorem, you can make all the non-divisible terms by $p$ vanish (you group together $1,2,\ldots,p-1$, then $p+1, \ldots, 2p-1$, and so on). Hence, mod $p$,  $$\frac{1}{p}\binom{p^2}{kp}=\frac{p \cdot 2p \cdot \ldots \cdot (p-1)p \cdot p}{p \cdot \ldots \cdot kp \cdot p \cdot \ldots \cdot (p-k)p}=\frac{1}{p}\binom{p}{k}=\frac{1}{k}\binom{p-1}{k-1}.$$

Now, mod $p$, $$(k-1)!(p-k)!=(k-1)!\prod_{i=1}^{p-k}{i}=(k-1)!(-1)^{p-k}\prod_{i=1}^{p-k}{(p-i)}=(k-1)!(-1)^{p-k}\prod_{i=k}^{p-1}{i}=(-1)^{p-k}(p-1)!,$$ hence $$\binom{p-1}{k-1}=(-1)^{p-k}.$$

Therefore, if $0 < k < p$, mod $p$, $$\frac{1}{p}\binom{p^2}{kp}=(-1)^{p-k}k^{-1}.$$